# References in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I got tossed into some maintenance work on a classic ASP (note: NOT ASP.NET) page. This page has a line that looks like this at the top:

```
<object RUNAT="server" PROGID="findasp.Search" id="objFind"></object>
```

The body of the asp page then has something that looks like this:

```
<form ACTION="search.asp" METHOD="post" ID="frmSearch" NAME="frmSearch">    
  <% objFind.Display "", "" %> 
</form>
```

What is the world is this doing? It looks like it is calling the Display function. This function than spits out some HTML. From my guess, the Display function is defined through the objFind object. However, I can't find how objFind is defined or where it is defined.

Can someone please give me some advice? I have no clue where to go with this at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is using a [server side object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8k45y06.aspx) - this would be a com object with the name (PROGID) `findasp.Search` assigned to the variable (`id` in the tag) `objFind`.

This com object seems to define a `Display` function, however without knowing more about `findasp.Search` there isn't much more I can tell.